# JavaFx 2.0 main window closes despite event being consumed

Tags: java, javafx-2

If there are unsaved changes, I want to prevent my application (class `Foo`) from closing after the user clicks the window close control (the 'X' in the window frame). Following tips here and elsewhere, I have `Foo` implement `EventHandler<WindowEvent>`. The `handle()` method queries the controller for unsaved changes and, if it finds any, consumes the event. The structure looks as follows.

```
public class Foo extends Application implements EventHandler<WindowEvent> {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Foo.fxml"));
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
    controller = (FooController) loader.getController();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(this);  // handle window close requests
    stage.show();
  }

  @Override
  public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
    if (t.getEventType() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST) {
      if (controller.isDirty()) {
        t.consume();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using print statements and the debugger, I confirmed that the handler fires and the event is consumed. I also confirmed that the `Application.stop()` method is never called. Nonetheless, as soon as `handle()` exits, the window closes. (The application's thread is still running, though.) For what it's worth, the application is just a stub: the scene is drawn, but none of the menu items or controls function, it creates no additional threads, etc.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a small test app. Consuming the event does prevent the window from closing. Looking at the code you posted, I have no idea why it doesn't work for you. Could you

a) state the JavaFX-Version you are using (`System.out.println(com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion());`) and

b) run the code below and tell me whether this works for you?

I'm trying to find out whether it's a bug in JavaFX or some side effect within your application.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class Test extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            public void handle(final WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                windowEvent.consume();
            }
        });
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The JavaFX version is 2.2.7-b01. I ran your code and got an empty stage (other than the usual minimize/maximize/close buttons). I clicked the close button and the window closed (but left the thread running). Don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm running on Linux Mint 14 Nadia (64 bit).